# Plugin shortcodes not working in custom theme

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I originally made [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/249357/ninja-forms-shortcode-not-producing-intended-results-in-custom-wordpress-theme), thinking that my problem was specific to the Ninja Forms plugin (the original post was obviously put on hold, for being off-topic). My reason for thinking so, was that WordPress' native gallery shortcode was working correctly, but it would seem that the issue affects **all** plugin shortcodes.

As this is no longer an issue with a specific plugin, but WordPress's ability to execute plugin shortcodes -- --, I've taken the liberty to assume that it is now considered on-topic.

Even with an empty *functions.php* file and the following as my only code, the issue still persists.

```
<?php
  if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
      the_content();
    endwhile;
  endif;
?>
```

When inspecting the page, this appears to output **some** of what it's supposed to, in the form of a script or div, but it's as if the plugins are never rendered, despite being initialized.

I've been stuck here for a few days now, so if anyone could give me a push in the right direction, that would be amazing!

**Note:** I apologize if this is still considered to be off-topic. In case it is, please disregard this post.

Comment: does your theme have `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()`?

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out by [Michael](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/4884/michael), I had been missing the `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` functions.

To anyone who might be in the same boat as I, you can have a look at the function references [here (head)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) and [here (footer)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer).

Thank you, to anyone who took their time to help me out, even if all they did was read the question. I'm glad we reached a conclusion so quickly!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to active the default wordpress theme like twenty eleven or like that and then see if the problem persist ?

If it is still there can you show a URL of your site so that I can have a look at it. Also please add the shortcode in that page which URL you are sharing with me.

Comment: Can you Please check this question → https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/276227/shortcode-not-working-and-the-relation-to-the-content