# shortcode not working and the relation to the_content()

Tags: shortcode, the-content

[Reference Post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/276182/why-is-the-shortcode-not-working)  (I was even downvoted here.)

My short code was not working on my custom theme, but the same short code, when used in twenty fifteen, was working.

I researched over google and found that it was something related to not using the_content correctly.

1. https://kb.yoast.com/kb/shortcodes-not-rendering/
2. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/shortcodes-not-working-custom-theme/

I applied the solution suggested in the Yoast →

that means I changed from

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

TO

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content ); ?>
```

But still, the shortcodes are not working.

what is the working fix?

I have this code in single.php →

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                            <?php $post_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
                            <?php get_template_part('content',get_post_format()); ?>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
```

and in content.php →

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

[image]

## ON LIVE PAGE→

[image]

FULL SHORTCODE →

```
function simplisto_the_image($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'to' => 'https://pics.wikifeet.com/Melania-Trump-Feet-720891.jpg'
    ), $atts);
    $output = '<div class="lazyimg">';
            $output .= '<img class="lazyimg-popup" src="'.$atts['to'].'" alt="The First Caption" width="100%" height="auto">';
        $output .= '<i class="fa fa-expand" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    return $output;
}

function register_shortcodes(){
   add_shortcode('simage', 'simplisto_the_image');
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

Comment: Try echo do_shortcode( get_the_content() );

Comment: You said you changed the_content() to apply_filters, but then you say content.php has the_content().... it should have apply_filters no?

Comment: Actually i tried with apply_filters as posted in my question, but that also didn't Worked.

Comment: what is the exact full code of your shortcode function? does the same problem exist when you use one of the generic shortcodes like [gallery]?

Comment: ps: are you using any postformat for the post?

Comment: I tried  [gallery] → No Problem sir. I am updating the full shortcode.

Comment: No Postformat defined yet.

Comment: I tried [gallery] → It works.

Comment: Can you try to replace function register_shortcodes()...to the end with  just add_shortcode('simage', 'simplisto_the_image');

Comment: should I also delete this → `add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');  ?
`

Comment: I did, but still the same issue. https://www.screencast.com/t/HRP060RONwDq

Comment: Leaving for the day sir. It is 4:21 AM here in India.

Comment: Sir, Is any one still here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excuse brief answer (writing on train in iPhone) but I would try changing `get_template_part()` to its non-WordPress `include()` equivalent as, from memory, variables declared outside your `content.php` won't be available otherwise.

Comment: @Jack Johansson Any clue?

Comment: even if I am trying this in content.php → `<?php echo do_shortcode("[simage]"); ?>` still it is not generating the [DESIRED OUTPUT](https://www.screencast.com/t/Nflx4so1). there is something else that is fundamentally missing in the theme. I have no clue what is that?

Comment: Please guide me one step further sir. Please help.

Comment: I have accepted the answer.